# Mocha tests cases not waiting before to complete

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js

I'm writing test cases with mocha in Nodejs and want to reset database data before running the tests. I'm using Knex as query builder for executing queries.

I wrote following logic:

```
describe('Activities:', function() {

  before(funtion(){
   activityDBOperations.deleteAll()
   .then(function(){
       // all records are deleted
   });
  });

  it('it should add a record into Activities table: multiple time activity',  function(done) {
    activityDBOperations.addRecord(requestParams)
        .then(function(data) {
            expect(data.length > 0).to.equal(true);
            done();
        });
  });
});
```

The problem is that test cases start executing and not waiting for deleteAll operation to finish. What I understand is since deleteAll is returning promise, the program execution move forward because of asynchronous nature of promises.

How can I make sure that test cases should run only when deleteAll has finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either provide a callback to your `before` hook and call it in `then`:

```
before(function(done) {
   activityDBOperations.deleteAll()
     .then(function() {
         // all records are deleted
         done();
     });
});
```

or, according to [Mocha docs](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises), just return a promise from `before`:

```
before(function() {
   return activityDBOperations.deleteAll();
});
```

Comment: That is what I told you.

Answer (score -1):

Add return statements so the Promises are actually returned.

Comment: I want **it** to work after then :( , promise is being returned.

Comment: That is what I told you.

Comment: Maybe you should provide an example next time. @JasonLivesay